# Seekbar value cannot be seen in the textview field

Tags: android, seekbar

I have 3 seekbars in android.

I wish to display the value of the texview everytime a user picks these seekbars and modify them accordingly.I have put the setText function in the onStopTrackingTouch method . But all it displays is a 0. 
Can someone pls help.
Thanks.

My code :

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import app.minimize.com.seek_bar_compat.SeekBarCompat;

public class BudgetActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public TextView seekbarvalue;
    int groceryvalue,restaurantvalue,enterntainmnetvalue,totalvalueset,totalbudget=1000;
    boolean isGrocerySet,isEntertainmnetSet,isRestaurantSet;
    SeekBarCompat groceryseekBarCompat,entertainmentseekBarCompat,restaurantseekbarCompat;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_budget);

       // CrystalSeekbar groceryseekBarCompat = (CrystalSeekbar) findViewById(R.id.grocerySeekBar);

        groceryseekBarCompat = (SeekBarCompat) findViewById(R.id.groceryseekbar);
        groceryseekBarCompat.setThumbColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        groceryseekBarCompat.setProgressColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        groceryseekBarCompat.setProgressBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        groceryseekBarCompat.setThumbAlpha(128);
        groceryseekBarCompat.setMax(totalbudget);

        entertainmentseekBarCompat = (SeekBarCompat) findViewById(R.id.entertainmentseekbar);
        entertainmentseekBarCompat.setThumbColor(Color.RED);
        entertainmentseekBarCompat.setProgressColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        entertainmentseekBarCompat.setProgressBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        entertainmentseekBarCompat.setThumbAlpha(128);
        entertainmentseekBarCompat.setMax(totalbudget);

        restaurantseekbarCompat = (SeekBarCompat) findViewById(R.id.restaurantseekbar);
        restaurantseekbarCompat.setThumbColor(Color.YELLOW);
        restaurantseekbarCompat.setProgressColor(Color.CYAN);
        restaurantseekbarCompat.setProgressBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        restaurantseekbarCompat.setThumbAlpha(128);
        restaurantseekbarCompat.setMax(totalbudget);

        seekbarvalue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekbarvalue) ;


        /**
         *  Listener for grocery seekbar
         */

        groceryseekBarCompat.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBarCompat.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                          boolean fromUser) {
                seekbarvalue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("Grocery on start" ,"clicked");
                totalvalueset = totalvalueset - seekBar.getProgress();
                Log.d("On start totalvalueset" ,String.valueOf(totalvalueset));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                groceryvalue = seekBar.getProgress();
                Log.d("Seekbar progress" ,String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));
               // seekbarvalue.setText(String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));
                if(totalvalueset <=1000) {
                    totalvalueset += groceryvalue;
                }

                Log.d("Grocery on stop" ,String.valueOf(groceryvalue));
                Log.d("totalvalueset++++++" ,String.valueOf(totalvalueset));
                isGrocerySet = true;
                isEntertainmnetSet = false;
                isRestaurantSet = false;
                setDynamicLimit();
            }
        });



        /**
         * Listener for the enterntainment seekbar
         */

        entertainmentseekBarCompat.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBarCompat.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                          boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                seekbarvalue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("Enterntainment on start" ,"clicked");
                totalvalueset = totalvalueset - seekBar.getProgress();
                Log.d("On start totalvalueset" ,String.valueOf(totalvalueset));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                enterntainmnetvalue = seekBar.getProgress();

                if(totalvalueset <=1000)  {
                    totalvalueset += enterntainmnetvalue;
                }
                Log.d("Entertainment on stop" ,String.valueOf(enterntainmnetvalue));
                Log.d("totalvalueset+++++" ,String.valueOf(totalvalueset));
                seekbarvalue.setText(String.valueOf(enterntainmnetvalue));
                isEntertainmnetSet = true;
                isGrocerySet = false;
                isRestaurantSet = false;
                setDynamicLimit();
            }
        });



        /**
         * Listener for the restaurant seekbar
         */

        restaurantseekbarCompat.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBarCompat.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                          boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                restaurantvalue = progress;
                seekbarvalue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("Restaurant on start" ,"clicked");
                totalvalueset = totalvalueset - seekBar.getProgress();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                restaurantvalue = seekBar.getProgress();
                seekbarvalue.setText(String.valueOf(restaurantvalue));
               if(totalvalueset <=1000) {
                   totalvalueset+=restaurantvalue;
               }
                Log.d("Restaurant on stop" ,String.valueOf(restaurantvalue));
                Log.d("totalvalueset++" ,String.valueOf(totalvalueset));
                isRestaurantSet = true;
                isGrocerySet = false;
                isEntertainmnetSet = false;
                setDynamicLimit();
            }
        });

    }

    private void setDynamicLimit() {
            Log.d("setting dynamic limit" , String.valueOf(totalbudget-totalvalueset));
           if(!isEntertainmnetSet) entertainmentseekBarCompat.setMax(totalbudget-totalvalueset);
           if(!isRestaurantSet) restaurantseekbarCompat.setMax(totalbudget-totalvalueset);
            if(!isGrocerySet) groceryseekBarCompat.setMax(totalbudget-totalvalueset);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your first seekbar doesn't have a `setText` on stop tracking. Are log values coming in properly?

Comment: I missed to add them. But it ain't working for other values too

Comment: Since you are also setting the value in `onPreogressChanged()`, why are you also setting it in `onStopTrackingTouch()`? I think `onProgressChanged()` should do the trick. Are the log values good?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `progress` to pass the TextView like this:

yourTextViewName.setText("" + progress + "");

Hope this helps.helps.